# How to gray out an event on FullCalendar?

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery fullcalendar plugin [FullCalendar v2.1.1](http://fullcalendar.io) to display user events.

I am populating the calendar with events using a PHP script.

What I want to do is to gray out an event if that event are already completed.

In my PHP script I can tell if an event is already completed or not by doing checking the status variable

```
if($status == 2)
    $fc['className'] = 'fc-past-custom';
```

Then I have added a fc-past-custom class to the very bottom of the `fullcalendar.css` file
However, this is not adding a class to the event block for some reason.

How, can I gray out the event if the event is already completed. Yes I have reasons why I want to display completed events.

Comment: Please show your jquery/ajax code where you are calling the php script

Comment: You can use the eventRender callback and set your own class on the element like "completed" or something where you style the event gray

Comment: If you recall in my [answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26152742/1810243), I showed some excessive manipulation of an event title/time in the `eventRender`. You can use similar logic to change the class.

Comment: Though it could be easier just to do it on the server and set the colors in your actual event source. ie just set the `"borderColor":"#222","color":"#444","textColor":"#ccc"`. [demo and json source](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/demo-fullcalendar-with-event-filtering/)